# Select in HTML FORM + IMAGE UPLOAD + PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hello I have one big question. I have php code and a html form with image upload input and also some text input places and its working fine, but I want to add dropdown select in my form. But after I placed the select element in my code its not longer uploading the photo to the server and not pasting the mysql data into my database. I hope you can help me.

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])){

        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];      
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        if($file_name){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"images/$file_name");
        }
    }
?>
```

```
<?php
    include 'includes/upload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['upload_img']) && $_POST['upload_img']=="submit")
    {
        $image = $file_name;
        $car_number = addslashes($_POST['car_number']);
        $manufacture = addslashes($_POST['manufacture']);
        $model = addslashes($_POST['model']);
        $year = addslashes($_POST['year']);
        $transmission = addslashes($_POST['transmission']);
        $type = addslashes($_POST['type']);
        $currency = addslashes($_POST['currency']);
        $km_mileage = addslashes($_POST['km_mileage']);
        $fuel_type = addslashes($_POST['fuel_type']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO my_garage (image,car_number,manufacture,model,year,transmission,type,currency,km_mileage,fuel_type) VALUES ('$image', '$car_number','$manufacture','$model','$year','$transmission','$type','$currency','$km_mileage','$fuel_type')";
        if($result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()))
        {
            echo "uspeshno.<br>";
        }
    }else{
?>

        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">



        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label>upload image</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image"><br>
        <br><br>

        car_number:
        <input name="car_number" type="text"><br><br>


        <select class="browser-default" name="manufacture">
            <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
            <option value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
            <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
        </select>

        manufacture:
        <input name="manufacture" type="text"><br><br>
        model:
        <input name="model" type="text"><br><br>
        year:
        <input name="year" type="text"><br><br>
        transmission:
        <input name="transmission" type="text"><br><br>
        type:
        <input name="type" type="text"><br><br>
        currency:
        <input name="currency" type="text"><br><br>
        km_mileage:
        <input name="km_mileage" type="text"><br><br>
        fuel_type:
        <input name="fuel_type" type="text"><br><br>

        <input name="upload_img" class="btn" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think the line "$_POST['upload_img']=="submit" is unnecessary. As I'm reading the code, I don't think $_POST['upload_img'] could have any other value other than submit.

Comment: Also, why do you need "addslashes($_POST['manufacture'])". There don't seem to be any options in 'manufacture' that have escape chars?

Answer (score 0):

I think the current code don't work, because you have two html elements with the name `manufacture`. Try to remove the input field (`<input name="manufacture" type="text">`).

Answer (score 0):

There may be error because addslashes with dropdown.